# How bind a event and use apply/call to change the scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  var popup = {
    init: function(element) {
      this._active = 'products__popup--active';
      this._product = $('.products__popup');
      this._element = $('[data-popup-to]');
      this._TIME = 500;

      popup.attachEvt();
    },

    attachEvt: function() {
      var that = this;

      that._element.bind('click', popup.handlerEvt.call(that));
    },

    handlerEvt: function() {
      console.log(this);
      console.log('test');
    }
  };

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    popup.init();    
  });

}(jQuery);
```

I have this script, and is not working yet, I cant show you a working example because it is not ready, I'm organizing the code first.

And there is a problem with the `attachEvt` function, inside it I want to call another function of my object, this function will bind a click in the `that._element`, but I want pass to the `handlerEvt` the scope of `this` (the clicked element) and the `that` (the object), but this is not working:

```
that._element.bind('click', popup.handlerEvt.call(that));
```

I'm just passing the that scope and when the script loads, the element will be clicked without click, I want avoid this.. this is possible?

---

UPDATE:

Resuming:

I want be able to use the scope of the object (that) and the scope of the clicked element (this) inside the `handlerEvt` function, but without make the event click when the script loads.. :B

Comment: `popup.handlerEvt.bind(this)` Obviously, the `this` can't refer to two different objects at the same time. Instead use `event.currentTarget` in place of `this` to get the clicked element.

Comment: Or heck, why not just have `handlerEvt` refer to `popup` directly?

Comment: didn't get the comment, can you show with a answer?

Comment: I mean that the object you seem to want to have your methods refer to is `popup`, so why not just have them reference that variable directly instead of trying to use `this`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `.bind()` , with `this` set to `that._element` , `that` passed as parameter to `handlerEvent` . Note order of parameters at `handlerEvent`: `obj`: `that` first , `evt` `event` object second

```js
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  var popup = {
    init: function(element) {
      this._active = 'products__popup--active';
      this._product = $('.products__popup');
      this._element = $('[data-popup-to]');
      this._TIME = 500;

      popup.attachEvt();
    },

    attachEvt: function() {
      var that = this;

      that._element.bind('click', popup.handlerEvt.bind(that._element, that));
    },

    handlerEvt: function(obj, evt) {
      console.log(evt, obj, this);
      console.log('test');
    }
  };

  $(window).on('load', function() {
    popup.init();    
  });

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-popup-to="true">click</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, that helped me understood for futures uses :)

Comment: `that._element.bind('click', popup.handlerEvt.bind(that._element, that));` You're binding an element that will have the `this` value anyway. Might as well just do `this._element.bind("click", popup.handlerEvt);` If he wants to refer to the `popup` instead (which is what it seems), then he might as well just use the `popup` variable like he's doing in the other methods instead of binding it to `this`.

Comment: @squint Attempted to meet requirement at OP _"want pass to the handlerEvt the scope of this (the clicked element) and the that (the object)"_